# GroupBy common values between different columns of two DataFrames

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a `dataframe A`:

```
col1  col2  score
 A      2    30
 B      6    20
 C      8    15
 D      7    70
 E      2    35
```

Another `dataframe B`:

```
col1  col2  score
 8      B    30
 3      C    20
 6      E    15
 1      D    70
 2      A    35
```

I want to merge two dataframes in a way that groupby  `col1` from `dataframe A` to the `col2` of `dataframe B` while averaging the `score` from two dataframes in descending order.
For example:

```
result  avg_score
 D        70
 A        32.5
 B        25
 E        25
 C        17.5
```

Comment: It looks like `((df_a.set_index('col1')['score'] + df_b.set_index('col2')['score']) / 2).rename_axis(index='result').reset_index(name='avg_score').sort_values('avg_score', ascending=False)` but I'm unclear is there a chance that there could be multiple duplicates in col1/col2 or are they guaranteed to be unique?

Comment: There is only one duplicate not multiple...

Comment: @HenryEcker your solution seems working, Thank you so much.

Comment: Another option would be concat : ``pd.concat([df1.set_index('col1').score, df2.set_index('col2').score]).groupby(level=0).mean()``